# IIS 7.5 Windows 2008 R2 Gives 500 remotely and custom 404 locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, custom-error-pages

I've created the following base controller to show a custom 404 on InvalidOperationException (view not found for instance).

```
public class HandlesViewNotFoundController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //InvalidOperationException is thrown if the path to the view
        // cannot be resolved by the viewengine
        if (filterContext.Exception is InvalidOperationException)
        {
            if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "_404" };
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                Response.Clear();

                // Clear the error on server.
                Server.ClearError();

                // Avoid IIS7 getting in the middle
                Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            }
        }
        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I open a page that would trigger a 404, it works perfectly locally when debugging, and locally when viewing the page on the server, but if I view the same url that I checked on the server remotely, an internal server error (500) is returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: I take it the view _404 is in the shared folder and is a full view (I ask because partial views are typically prefixed with an underscore) and is marked as "Content" in properties?

Comment: It's indeed in Shared and marked as Content; it's a page that inherrits from the _Layout.cshtml I've just followed naming shared resources with _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that customeErrors attribute is configured correctly in the web.config (and the deployed transform) and comment out the global filter HandleError.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Comment: Thanks; that was it. I guess I'll have to look into how that HandleErrorAttribute works, and I find it strange that the behaviour can differ when viewing the site locally on the webserver and externally, for this attribute.

Comment: Here's a good place to start - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute(v=vs.108).aspx and if you are using the default web.config it contains customErrors mode="Off" and is typically transformed by web.Release.config to something like customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" which is why you see different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you forgot to deploy the view file _404 to the server.

Comment: Nope; as I said; when I view the page that gives a 404 from the server, it works with the custom 404 page.